# Selenium c# - Button click fails in Firefox...but only when using WebDriver

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium

Here's my dilemma...
I have a button that becomes un-clickable in a browser window opened using WebDriver.

The button:

```
<div class="ribbon-section">
<span class="section-title" data-bind="text: title">Email</span>
<div class="layout" data-bind="css: { 'vertical': isVertical ,layout:true}">
<div id="email-btn" class="ribbon-control ribbon-button ribbon-button-large" data-bind="attr: { id: id }, css: { disabled: disabled, 'ribbon-button-large': size() == 'large', 'ribbon-button-small': size() == 'small', 'ribbon-button-medium': size() == 'medium' }, click: onClick">
<img class="ribbon-icon ribbon-normal" data-bind="attr: { src: imgNormal }, visible: !disabled()" src="/_layouts/15/klscript/content/images/ribbon/normal/email-link.png" style="">
<img class="ribbon-icon ribbon-disabled" data-bind="attr: { src: imgDisabled }, visible: disabled()" src="/_layouts/15/klscript/content/images/ribbon/disabled/email-link.png" style="display: none;">
<span class="control-title" data-bind="html: title">Email Link</span>
<span class="control-help" data-bind="text: tooltip">Email Link</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's not that WebDriver cannot locate the element or anything like that. The button simply can't be clicked, by WebDriver or manually.  Nothing happens.
If I open Firefox manually, the button is clickable.

I have tried this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("email-btn")).Click();
```

and this:

```
IWebElement emailBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("email-btn"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.Click(emailBtn);
```

and this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('email-btn').click()");
```

Comparing it with another button that has no issue, I see that they are the same, aside from the Id:

```
<div id="email-btn" class="ribbon-control ribbon-button ribbon-button-large" data-bind="attr: { id: id }, css: { disabled: disabled, 'ribbon-button-large': size() == 'large', 'ribbon-button-small': size() == 'small', 'ribbon-button-medium': size() == 'medium' }, click: onClick">

<div id="download-item-btn" class="ribbon-control ribbon-button ribbon-button-large" data-bind="attr: { id: id }, css: { disabled: disabled, 'ribbon-button-large': size() == 'large', 'ribbon-button-small': size() == 'small', 'ribbon-button-medium': size() == 'medium' }, click: onClick">
```

Also tried disabling images and/or css in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 'disabled: disabled' from the elements css. You should be all set after that

Comment: I thought so, too...but if I compare another button(that has no issues), I see that they are the same.

Comment: Trust me, try to remove the disabled property. Can you share the url of the page you're trying to scrape? I can tell you for sure that way.